# How may I suggest edits to a CV?

Tags: support, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs, etiquette

Is there a way to (privately) suggest spelling/grammar improvements to someone's *curriculum vitæ* (CV)?

While searching through answers, I found an answer to which I want to say 'thank you'. Of course, I up-voted it. If I had more rep, I would consider awarding additional rep points, but I don't yet.

When looking for an 'out-of-the-box' solution to my gratitude problem, I noticed that the user has been active today, and that the user's CV, while up to date and quite good for a non-English speaker, has a few typos, and some usage inaccuracies that an English speaker would never allow on their own CV. Far be it from me to say that everyone must work in an English speaking environment, but I think it a safe assumption that an English language CV expresses that desire.

While I am no programmer, I am an IT Project Manager, and I have some experience with reading CVs. How can I be helpful and suggest some improvements?

I want to do it in such a way that others don't see my notes (that would be rude to the owner of the CV), and the CV owner never even has to acknowledge that they got it (not interested in invading privacy).

I have no desire to completely wordsmith the guys CV, as that is often poorly received even when solicited. Just things like 'little kid' instead of 'small kid' (context shows attempting to describe age, not size), or 'our' instead of 'out' (context shows attempting to show ownership, not preposition).

Comment: The pedant in me can't help -- in a post about correcting English -- pointing out that "_to completely wordsmith the guys CV_" should be "_guy's_" (while hoping I've not made any mistakes in this comment).  To answer the question, I think a private email should be the only way for this (with suitable disclaimer along the lines "_Feel free to ignore, but you may find the following suggestions useful..._").

Comment: *cough* I just had do check whether those examples came from my CV. I'd appreciate constructive criticism though, so if it were mine I'd welcome your input, be it as email or any other means of contact mentioned in the CV.

Comment: @TripeHound Love it! Good Call! :) I suppose if I were in a different mood I could say that a posting on meta is not nearly as important as my CV, but we all know that the internet is forever, and probably a better gauge of my ability and personality than a 3 page CV ("three!? is he crazy?!?") covering some selected past successes. So... oops! :) Oh, and I am going to leave it, for posterity. And because your comment is funny.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I appreciate the motivation, and the desire for a simple "edit this CV" feature is understandable, given how weird actively offering corrections to strangers' CVs through E-Mail can look.

But that - contacting the individual through whatever means they have published - is really the only way, and it should stay that way: edits to CVs should never become a formalized feature within the system. There's just too many potential problems.

Imagine the huge possibilities for abuse, for example - like a prankster suggesting subtly bad edits to folks who don't speak the language well. Given the infrastructure you'd have to create to monitor all this, the potential benefits seem unlikely to be big enough.

Comment: It's a good point to bring up the possibilities for abuse, but there's no reason that the truly dedicated couldn't just suggest the same things in an email (but that would be outside SO's control). Actually, I think that the current system of edits (assuming robos aren't an issue) would work well, since trolls can be banned.

Comment: @Laurel Please explain this 'current system of edits' to me, as if I were a small child... I can't seem to find any system of editing/commenting a CV directly. Am I dense?

Comment: @CWilson the "current system of edits" is that of posts, not CVs.

Comment: @Laurel it's not that I don't find the idea of crowdsourced CV help intriguing. But it would mean a whole new world of complexity and pain - for something that is infinitely more important and personal than a SO question. SO can handle vandalism on a question, even if it shows up for a couple of minutes. The same can't be said of CVs. This idea is a non-starter.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Simple grammatical edits isn't really crowd-sourcing. But I do understand how much work this would be to maintain given all the issues we already have with robo reviewers on the SO edit system. I hope that people wouldn't trust the judgement of a stranger's email blindly. I don't participate in CVs/Jobs/Careers, but I would think that there is some group of people who are official and trustworthy enough to proofread things. Like some type of mod maybe.

Comment: @Laurel yeah, maybe it could work unter some sort of mentoring banner - experienced (and reputable, SO-wise) IT folk offering support for people's CVs. Not a bad idea, but not sure whether it fits under the SO brand

Comment: I think it fits under the SO brand the same way that careers or jobs fits under the brand - it benefits developers.

Comment: Additionally, there would be a huge difference between how edits are accepted in the current system and in the CV system: the CV owner would *always* be in full control of what their CV displays, so they'd *always* need to explicitly *accept* edit suggestions. The system would therefore not be very susceptible to reviewer-fatigue or the like. Frankly, I think it's premature to *assume* that this would provide major opportunities for abuse. (Even English-language learners can often tell the difference between good and bad English more easily than they can craft good English on their own.)

Comment: Also, if an ELL receives a CV edit-suggestion that they don't understand, they can ask about it on ELL.SE, which will quickly expose the user who suggested the editor as a "prankster" (as you put it).

Comment: @KyleStrand We can go a step further.  People with less than, say, 10k reputation could have their CV edit suggestions reviewed by other people *before* they are even presented to the owner of the CV.  And people over (say) 10k would have their edit suggestions both reviewed *and* presented to the CV owner, where if the review rejects it it is withdrawn from being shown to the CV owner.  Maybe with a "anyone rejects, edit is rejected" rule. In an attempt to make pranks less likely...

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I was definitely thinking that there would still be a curation process via the review-queue. Pranks seem like a *very* small concern with those precautions.

Comment: I think the comments on Pekka웃's answer have gotten away from his intent, I think, and this line of thought might be really an additional answer, but let me add my (uninformed) 2 cents: wouldn't a review queue, by definition, highlight those unintentional errors that we are hoping to discretely improve without calling attention to? How could we implement such a queue without possibly embarrassing the author of any CV found in that queue? It would of necessity be an opt in solution, I think, which doesn't really solve my initial gratitude problem.

Answer (score 12):

For the purposes of this question we need to clarify what "suggesting edits" means in context. Most users who have been around for even a while will probably instinctively think of an edit suggestion system not unlike what we have in place for posts.

But a CV is a personal document, not a wiki. A Stack Overflow user's CV is much like their professional profile, if you will. You don't go around making corrections to other people's user profiles or websites *on their behalf* — you wouldn't do the same with someone's CV, physical or digital. We have an editing system for posts and that's because posts are collaborative works first and foremost, by design. But that's not the case for user profiles, or CVs, which is why they are completely read-only to anyone but the owner.

If you spot writing issues in someone else's work, and want them to know about it, there's nothing wrong with contacting them through appropriate means (e.g. don't email them unless they put their email address on their profile) and *suggesting* that they fix those issues; in fact, I'm sure they'll appreciate the heads-up. But let *them* make the changes themselves — after all, it's *their* content, and they have full control over it.

Comment: What about creating a private chat room and leaving few messages mentioning the user? Is that possible/considered abuse of chat system? No one seems to have mentioned chat so just wondering.

Comment: @T J: I wouldn't say it's abuse, but creating a chat room might seem excessive to some.

Comment: See the Yakk's and my comments on Pekka's answer. I think edit-suggestions for a CV could still have value.

Comment: @Kyle Strand: Again this is all predicated on the idea that CVs are collaborative works, which they simply are not, unless Stack Overflow has every intention of revolutionizing that notion.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no one is proposing a system that will actually allow people  to *edit* another person's CV--only to facilitate *suggesting* CV changes. Full owernship of the CV is retained by the person whose name is on it.

Comment: @TJ I am no expert here, just the OP. Some new guy that was expecting a yes/no answer. That said, a chat room directly contradicts one of my personal priorities of privacy, a priority that even outweighs my priority of being nice to people that help me, especially without knowing they do so. I think it would be rude to point out spelling errors of a stranger only because they did something nice to me that was totally unrelated to the document that they made the unintentional error in.